# sed pattern replace " to \" and \ to \\ except json string

Tags: text-processing, sed

I've got problem to replace `"` to `\"` and `\` to `\\` and except `"` of json

`test.txt` input file

```
"a"     "b"     
{"1":"female","2":"197312","3":"359","4":"201109","5":"mail"}
\uff08\u524d\u5bfe\u5fdc
```

I want to output like

```
\"a\"     \"b\"     
{"1":"female","2":"197312","3":"359","4":"201109","5":"mail"}
\\uff08\\u524d\\u5bfe\\u5fdc
```

Comment: How complex is your file? Will the JSON string always be in a single line? Will the JSON string never contain `{` or `}`? Will there be multiple lines of data? Will the JSON data always be the only line(s) in the file that start with a `{`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be more robust, you could do a full json parsing:

```
perl -0777 -pe '
  s@(".*?"|\\)|(\{(?:"(?:\\.|[^"])*+"|(?2)|[^"{}]++)*+\})|[^{}\\"]+@
  $1 ? $1 =~ s/["\\]/\\$&/gr : $&@gse'
```

Which on an input like

```
"a"     "b"     "c{d"
{"1":"female","2":"197312","3":"359","4":"201109","5":"mail"}
{
  "1": {"x": "y"}
  "2": "}}}"
  "3": ["{\"x", "}"]
}
\uff08\u524d\u5bfe\u5fdc
```

gives

```
\"a\"     \"b\"     \"c{d\"
{"1":"female","2":"197312","3":"359","4":"201109","5":"mail"}
{
  "1": {"x": "y"}
  "2": "}}}"
  "3": ["{\"x", "}"]
}
\\uff08\\u524d\\u5bfe\\u5fdc
```

You may want to clarify what you want to do if the input contains `"foo\"bar"` or `"foo\nbar"` outside of json objects.

Comment: how about all data in one line?
like this
"a","b",{"1":"female","2":"197312","3":"359","4":"201109","5":"mail"},\uff08\u524d\u5bfe\u5fdc

Comment: @JOINMAX, how about it? The code above should change it to `\"a\",\"b\",{"1":"female","2":"197312","3":"359","4":"201109","5":"mail"},\\uff08\\u524d\\u5bfe\\u5fdc`, is it not what you want?

Answer (score 3):

In the simple example you show, this is easy. Just escape the characters only on lines that don't start with a `{`:

```
$ sed -E '/^[^{]/s|(["\])|\\\1|g' file 
\"a\"     \"b\"     
{"1":"female","2":"197312","3":"359","4":"201109","5":"mail"}
\\uff08\\u524d\\u5bfe\\u5fdc
```

However, things get considerably more complicated if your JSON can span several lines. For such cases, you can write a little script that counts the number of opening `{` and closing `}` and only applies the replacement while those numbers are equal (so when we aren't in a JSON string). Something like:

```
perl -F'' -ne 'for (@F){$op++ if /{/; $cl++ if /}/; if($cl==$op){s|["\\]|\\$&|g;}print}' file
```

However, this will also break if the JSON string itself can contain `{` or `}` which don't signify a JSON section (e.g. `{"1":"b-{c}"}` or whatever). For such cases, use [Stéphane's approach](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/511456/22222) instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed 's/\(\\\|^"\|"$\|"[ \t]\)/\\\1/g' test.txt | sed 's/\([ \t]\)"/\1\\"/g'
```

- Replace `\` or `"` at start of line or end of line or before space/tab character:
  `'s/\(\\\|^"\|"$\|"[ \t]\)/\\\1/g'`
- or `"` after space/tab character: `sed 's/\([ \t]\)"/\1\\"/g'`

So this only works if your json string doesn't contain any space/tab characters and is on one line.